# Could mod bar be made more easy to understand?

Tags: feature-request

(moderator stuff, nothing interesting)

It's not that it's horribly broken.. But it's often freezes my brain, especially on comment flags.

Just look at this...

[image]

...and try to quickly figure out:

- what Feras Odeh asked and what it has to do with this flag? (*no idea and nothing*)
- is Steven the one flagging or the one being flagged? (*being flagged... who is flagging?*)
- what does grey `1` at the left means? (*comment upvoted, but not obvious that it's comment - layout is different from comment on site*)
- do `delete` and `dismiss` affect same target? (*they don't, delete is for comment, dismiss is for flag*)

Some of these you can figure out from hovers, but even knowing most of this stuff I still hit it like a wall on comment flags.